# How do I change the order in which lenses appear in the dash?

Tags: unity, unity-dash, lenses

Application lenses seem to be ordered alphabetically by default:

[image]

From left to right: dash home --> *applications* --> *extras-unity-lens-wikipedia* --> *files* --> *music* --> *recoll* --> *video*

Is there any way you can change this order? Perhaps by modifying the `.lens` files in `/usr/share/unity/lenses`?

I'd rather hear from someone who has done this already before messing around on my own.

Comment: if they do load alphabetically, you might be able to rename the folders that house lenses to 00-application.lens 10-music.lens 20-files.lens.  if it works let me know and i'll add in some details and flesh it out as an answer.

Comment: Thank you for the offer. I did some trial runs and it's almost like you said. I compiled an answer with the details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aking 1012 was right, almost. You have to change both the folder name and the `.lens` name in the folder for the change to take effect.

Head to */usr/share/unity/lenses*:

```
gksu nautilus /usr/share/unity/lenses
```

Rename both the lens folder and the `.lens` file to change their alphabetical order, e.g.:

*recoll* --> *yrecoll*

and

*recoll.lens* --> *yrecoll.lens*

I found that editing the default lenses was quite buggy and resulted in some scopes being disabled. That's why I settled for editing my custom lenses only. This is the result for *yrecoll* and *zwikipedia*:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can change dconf settings to re-order the lenses.

In the dash open **dconf-editor**.

Then, go to **com>caconical>unity>dash**.
Change the value of the key "home-lens-ordering" to the specific order you want.

I do not recommend changing folder/.lens name since whenever that specific lens calls the configuration file, it will not find it!

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I am glad to see that a more sane ordering method has been implemented. I take it you are running Ubuntu 12.10/13.04? On 12.04 there is no -->unity-->dash key as far as I can see.